# read array from json without any root object

Tags: python

I am using python 2.x. I am reading the following json from a file

[{"id":1, "name":"a"}, {"id":2,"name":"b"}]

I want to convert this json to an array of named tuple.

Is this possible or should I necessarily have a root element which contains the array?

code I wrote so far

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json
a = json.loads('''[{"id":1, "name":"a"}, {"id":2,"name":"b"}]''')
tuple = namedtuple('id', 'name')
mylist = [tuple(**k) for k in a]
```

I don't write python very frequently so please bear with me if this is a bad question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named tuples need a class name passed to them, and require attributes to be in one string. For example:

```
from collections  import namedtuple
import json
a = json.loads('''[{"id": 1, "name": "a"}, {"id": 2, "name": "b"}]''')
mytuple = namedtuple("mynamedtuple", "id, name")
mylist = [mytuple(**k) for k in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to do that in a simple manner :

```
import json        
json_file = "id.json"

objects = json.load(open(json_file))

annotations = objects

for annot in annotations:
    label = annot['class_name']
    print(label)
```